# WordPress 3.5 Changed User.php Which Breaks Plugin, Can this function be the issue? Can it be fixed?

Tags: plugins, authentication, wordpress, wordpress-3.5

A plugin provides login for a WordPress multi-site network. This plugin now fails under WP 3.5 because the user.php file was changed. The old lines in /wp-includes/user.php can be added back in and the plugin would work. Obviously this is not a long term solution.

This is the old code from user.php

```
if ( empty( $user ) )
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
else
    $user = new WP_User( $user );

if ( ! isset( $user->ID ) )
    return false;
```

This is the new code from 3.5

```
if ( empty( $user ) )
    $user = get_current_user_id();

if ( ! $user = get_userdata( $user ) )
    return false;
```

I'm a beginner trying to learn php and so I'm not sure on all of the meanings. However, I think this is the code in the plugin causing issue:

function get_userdata( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

```
if ( ! is_numeric( $user_id ) )
    return false;

$user_id = absint( $user_id );
if ( ! $user_id )
    return false;

$user = wp_cache_get( $user_id, 'users' ); //check to see if the cache object already has the user

if ( $user )
{
    return $user; //it was in the cache
}


    $user = new StdClass ();    

global $XF;
XF_User_Data::fillUserData($XF->visitor, $user, $user_id);

update_user_caches($user);

return $user;
```

}

The new StdClass can be commented out and the error is removed but then no one can login.

How could I re-write this function to not cause the error?

*Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::has_prop() /wp-includes/user.php*

The developer of the plugin is 'on vacation' and hasn't updated. He's waiting for some other changes, however, this needs to be fixed.

Any suggestions on fixing the code? Am I looking in the wrong place? Are other details needed before someone can help?

Comment: Have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata might give you some hint how to properly call get_userdata.

Comment: Thank you. I was just updating / playing around with the plugin's functions and saw get_userdata. I can comment out the $user = new StdClass but then no one can login.  I updated the original post to show the code in his plugin.

Comment: Changing the new StdClass line to $user = new WP_User( $user ) appears to have fixed the error as well as allows users to login.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are a skilled PHP programmer, modifying WP core or any plugin script is really a bad idea. In my opinion, you should downgrade to previous version and wait for the plugin's  update. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925312/upgrading-to-worpdress-3-5-erased-all-posts-and-pages-wiped-database/13927355#13927355) to do it easily. In fact, many plugins had problems with version 3.5, including the popular CKEditor, but they are being updated and in this case, waiting seems to be the best option. Make sure all plugins are compatible with 3.5 before trying another update.

Comment: I know not to modify the core. This is why I want the function in the plugin to be rewritten. I'm sorry my post was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you post which plugin you're using and a link to download it I'll take a look at it and see what the issue is.

Comment: Ok. This is a paid plugin. I just edited my original post because I've been playing with the function get_userdata and posted the plugin's version.